# Ошибка при сложении float (python)

Tags: python

Пытаюсь в цикле сложить float числа, на что получаю ошибку. Специально добавил вывод значений и их тип.

```
    for road in object_data['roadway_data']:
    if object_data['roadway_data'][road]['okrug_id'] in roadway:
        print(roadway[object_data['roadway_data'][road]['okrug_id']]['procent'], type(roadway[object_data['roadway_data'][road]['okrug_id']]['procent']))
        print(object_data['roadway_data'][road]['procent'], type(object_data['roadway_data'][road]['procent']))
        roadway[object_data['roadway_data'][road]['okrug_id']]['procent'] += object_data['roadway_data'][road]['procent'],
        roadway[object_data['roadway_data'][road]['okrug_id']]['num_exec'] += 1
    else:
        roadway[object_data['roadway_data'][road]['okrug_id']] = {'okrug_name': object_data['roadway_data'][road]['okrug_name'],
                                                                  'procent': object_data['roadway_data'][road]['procent'],
                                                                  'num_exec': 1}
```

[image: Вывод]

Данные - обычные словари.
Напоминать мне что в ошибке написано о сложении числа и списка не нужно. В первых строках ошибки указаны числа и их тип, но в цикле они не складываются.
Если просто сложить числа, все срабатывает как положено.
Даже предположить не могу в чем проблема.

Comment: приложите код текстом, пожалуйста

Comment: В ошибке говорится, что вы пытаетесь сложить переменную с типом `float` с `tuple`'ом. Ошибка эта возникает в 3 строке ифа (об этом также говорится в ошибке).

Comment: Скорее всего у вас то, что справа от `+=` недостаточно раскрыто, из-за чего это `tuple`

Comment: В первых строках вывод того, что складывается и их тип

Comment: Еще можете повыносить повторяющийся код в переменные, чтобы это было более читаемо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас стоит `,` в конце строки. `Python` воспринимает эту запись эквивалентной `(object_data['roadway_data'][road]['procent'], )`, а это не `float`, а `tuple`.
Решение проблемы - убрать запятую.

```
roadway[object_data['roadway_data'][road]['okrug_id']]['procent'] += object_data['roadway_data'][road]['procent']
```

Comment: *facepalm*
Мне нужно почаще включать голову. Спасибо!